# Email service by it.ozimov can't see the send method

Tags: email, spring-boot, sendmail, send, ozimov-email-tools

I implemented an email service form it.ozimov library. When everything was imported there is a problem with send method. I can't figure out how it should be imported, cause now the service can't see it.

Here it is dependency which I attach

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>it.ozimov</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-email-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>it.ozimov</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-freemarker-email</artifactId>
        <version>0.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here it is a service code

```
@Autowired
public EmailService emailService;

public void sendEmailWithoutTemplating() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    final Email email = DefaultEmail.builder()
            .from(new InternetAddress("cicero@mala-tempora.currunt", "Marco Tullio Cicerone "))
            .to(Lists.newArrayList(new InternetAddress("titus@de-rerum.natura", "Pomponius Attĭcus")))
            .subject("Laelius de amicitia")
            .body("Firmamentum autem stabilitatis constantiaeque eius, quam in amicitia quaerimus, fides est.")
            .encoding(String.valueOf(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))).build();

    emailService.send(email);
}
```

Of course I added below code at properties:

```
    spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=name.surname@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=V3ry_Str0ng_Password
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true

spring.mail.scheduler.persistence.enabled=false
spring.mail.scheduler.persistence.redis.embedded=false
spring.mail.scheduler.persistence.redis.enabled=false
```

Answer (score 1):

First, update the dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>it.ozimov</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-email-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>it.ozimov</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-freemarker-email</artifactId>
    <version>0.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, set the application properties:

```
spring.mail.host: smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port: 587
spring.mail.username: hari.seldon@gmail.com
spring.mail.password: Th3MuleWh0
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth: true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable: true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required: true
```

Finally create a test service

```
package com.test;

import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import it.ozimov.springboot.mail.model.Email;
import it.ozimov.springboot.mail.model.defaultimpl.DefaultEmail;
import it.ozimov.springboot.mail.service.EmailService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import static com.google.common.collect.Lists.newArrayList;

@Service
public class TestService {

    @Autowired
    private EmailService emailService;

    public void sendEmail() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        final Email email = DefaultEmail.builder()
                .from(new InternetAddress("hari.seldon@the-foundation.gal",
                        "Hari Seldon"))
                .to(newArrayList(
                        new InternetAddress("the-real-cleon@trantor.gov",
                        "Cleon I")))
                .subject("You shall die! It's not me, it's Psychohistory")
                .body("Hello Planet!")
                .encoding("UTF-8").build();

        emailService.send(email);
    }

}
```

Pay extreme attention to the packages being imported.

Finally, you need to enable the extension in your main app using the annotation

```
@EnableEmailTools
```

You can find more in [this article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/sending-scheduling-mime-emails-java-using-spring-boot-roberto-trunfio).